# What do you use for validation against XML schema?

Tags: java, validation, xsd

When I want to validate my XML docuemnts against a schema in my server-side Java, I use the built-in JRE Xerces implementation and javax.xml.validation.Schema.  It works fine, but when validation fails, Xerces gives error messages that are very close to useless, for example:

```
cvc-minLength-valid: Value '' with length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type 'PopulatedStringType'
```

These can take an age to diagnose and track down to the particular part of the XML document that fails validation, and all because of a poor error message.

So my question is, do you use an alternative means of validating XML against Schema, that gives a more useful output on validation failure?

Please not that this is server-side Java, so please don't say "use XML Spy" or similar.

Comment: sounds a fairly clear error message to me: it indicates that  the 'PopulatedStringType'specified in your XML schema had a minLength facet which was violated by your XML instance?

Comment: +1 @toolkit
You may want to consider spending a bit of time understanding Xerces error messages. I doubt another validator would be much clearer.

Comment: I understand the message just fine, but you try and find which part of a 10 meg XML document violates the schema when the error message doesn't tell you. These documents have thousands of elements of PopulatedStringType, with many different element names. Finding the right one is next to impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your handler for the validation, you should receive a SAXParseException with that message, as well as the [column number and the line number](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html#method_summary) in the XML file. Isnt't it the case?

Answer (score 0):

We use [Oracle's XDK (XML Development Kit)](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/xml/xdkhome.html) which includes xmlparserv2.jar with a validating parser and XSLT 2.0.  It uses the JAXB API so you should only have to add it to your classpath and change your imports.  It throws errors that aren't perfect, but I would say more easily understood than your example.

Answer (score 0):

xmlstarlet(xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is a command line toolkit. you could run it using Runtime.exec() for a given xml (as long as the xml is in a file).

Answer (score 0):

We use [Castor](http://www.castor.org).

> Castor is an Open Source data binding framework for Java[tm]. It's the shortest path between Java objects, XML documents and relational tables. Castor provides Java-to-XML binding, Java-to-SQL persistence, and more.

Comment: Why do you use Castor, and how does it help my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble interpreting the Xerces errors and would like something that helps to highlight where in your document you have violated the rules, check out some of the XML authoring tools such as [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/validation.html).

[image]
<sub>(source: [oxygenxml.com](http://www.oxygenxml.com/img/errorsOverviewRuler.gif))</sub>

Once you associate the schema with your instance XML document the editor will highlight the offending area of the document and provide you with a description of the violation.

Plus, you can use different engines to perform the validation:

> oXygen has built-in support for:
>   Xerces, LIBXML, XSV, Saxon SA,
>   MSXML4.0, MSXML .NET and SQC.